# whole iframe(in that page reCptcha include) not showing in Safari 6

Tags: php, ajax, iframe, google-chrome, safari

I am having 1 signup page , in that reCaptcha is included.
My whole website runs in php with fully AJAX.
Not a single page load done.
So i am not getting reCaptcha in dat page.

I try to put dat signup form in an separate page and called it using iframe.

SO now that whole iframe is not displayed in safari 6, and sometimes in Google Chrome also.

Please tell me what can i do??

Answer (score 0):

may be your browser is taking the page in quirks mode where recaptcha's  tag doesnot work. put a html `DOCTYPE` tag in your HTML/PHP file and that should solve the problem. If it is not the case then please post your source code so that we can assist.

> In case you dont know what is DOCTYPE
>   tag, a typical doctype tag looks like:
>
> `<!DOCTYPE html>`
>
> put that at the top of your html file
>   you want to load.

Comment: check signup page..You will find Google ReCaptcha over there.